# Print to array each time i press a button Xcode:

Tags: xcode

When I press the button I want the data to print to the array multiple times and populate in the table. I have the code for the table just need help with the textview or array or do I need a dictionary?

```
-(IBAction)share{
      
    if (textdata.text.length > 0)
    {
        alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Testimony" message:@"Posted Succcessfully: God Bless You" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        
        [alert1 show];

    }

    else
    {
        alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Testimony" message:@"Please Post your Testimony" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    
        [alert1 show];
    
    }
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:textdata.text, nil];
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by print the array. Do you have used table to showing data of array?

Answer (score 2):

I meant, each time you press the button for whats in the textview, how do you view the data in the tableview each time you press the button. The way I have it set up is that you press it once and it keeps overlapping the existing data. I want the data to be saved and stored in the tableview each time i press the button.